# Retrieving TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I have the following code sending frames from client 1 and from client 1 sending data to client 3.

Client-1 code

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://172.168.1.2:5555')
videoFile = 'data.mp4'
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile) 
length=int(camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
while True:        
  grabbed, frame = camera.read()
  try:
   frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
  except cv2.error:
    break
  encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
  jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
  footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
```

Client-2 code

```
footage_socket = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
footage_socket.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
PUB_TARGET = 'tcp://192.168.56.103:9999'
while True:    
   frame  = footage_socket.recv_string()                         
   source = cv2.imdecode( np.fromstring( base64.b64decode( frame ), dtype = np.uint8),1 )
   frame  = cv2.resize( source,
                     (224,224)
                     ).astype( "float32" )
   image = img_to_array( source )
   image = image.reshape( ( 1,image.shape[0],image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
   preds = model.predict( preprocess_input( image ) )
   ## connecting to server #######
   context1=zmq.Context()                          
   footage_socket = context1.socket( zmq.PUB )      
   footage_socket.connect( PUB_TARGET )            
   footage_socket.send(preds)
```

Server 1 code:

```
context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:9999')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
while True:
   frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
   img = base64.b64decode(frame)
   print(img)
```

While running the above code I am retrieving error in client 2 code

```py
   frame = footage_socket.recv_string()p
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/sugar/socket.py", line 583, in recv_string
    msg = self.recv(flags=flags)
   zmq.error.ZMQError: Operation not supported
   Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session 
   object at 0x7fa8c6a50908>>
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 707, in __del__
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect or bind your socket in client 2 before you try to receive.

```
footage_socket = context.socket( zmq.SUB )

>>> CONNECT OR BIND <<<<

PUB_TARGET = 'tcp://192.168.56.103:9999'
while True:    
   frame  = footage_socket.recv_string()
```

Comment: Thank you @JamesHarvey, it was a typo mistake by me I missed to include this in the question, I have updated the question. Thanks